# How to support dark mode for a UIlabelTextColor in iOS 13.x?

Tags: ios13, ios-darkmode

I Want the text color of UIlabel to be yellow on dark mode and black in normal mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a Color Sets in your asset catalog with different variants for light and dark mode:

[image: Color Asset]

You can then use the color in Interface Builder or code with `UIColor(named: "Color")`.
It will also adapt to appearance changes automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Schlegel